# Building a histogram from an array with: np.histogram

Tags: python

I would want to understand how np.histogram works, so I've run the following code:

```
import numpy as np 

a = np.array([[1,2,3,4],[1,2,3,4],[1,5,7,3]])
imhist , bins = np.histogram(a.flatten())
```

The problem is that I should get a histogram that shows [0,3,2,3,2,1,0,1], while I've got [3, 2, 0, 3, 0, 2, 1, 0, 0, 1]

What is going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first issue is that a default value for `bins=10` is passed in the call to `np.histogram`, you can fix that by passing the bins you want:

```
import numpy as np 

a = np.array([[1,2,3,4],[1,2,3,4],[1,5,7,3]])
imhist , bins = np.histogram(a.flatten(), bins=np.arange(9))

print(imhist, bins)

>>> (array([0, 3, 2, 3, 2, 1, 0, 1], dtype=int32),
     array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]))
```

In this case the bins go from 0 to 8 because you need to provide also the rightmost edge, so if your last value is 7, the rightmost bin edge will be 8.

Answer (score 0):

np.histogram defaults to having 10 bins. The bins determine how your data gets grouped. In your case you have 12 data values and 10 bins, which is why your bins aren't integers and your data gets adjusted.

Try using:

```
np.histogram(a.flatten(), bins=12)
```

instead :)

I hope this helps!

Comment: It returns [3, 0, 2, 0, 3, 0, 2, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1] with bins=12 but it should still be wrong. If I understood well, [3, 0, 2, 0, 3, 0, 2, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1] means that in the bin [0,1) there are 3 occurrences, in the bins [1,2) there aren't and so on.. It is wrong because I don't have any 0 in my array so I should get 0 how first element of the array, is it right?